# what is the servlet equivalent of Server.MapPath?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, servlets

I've got a folder in my Web Application, fonts. I'd like to get the path for each of those files in that directory. How do I do that? In asp.net I'd do something like:

```
 System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/fonts"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String path = ServletContext.getRealPath("/fonts");
```

[Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use method [getResourcePaths(String path)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths(java.lang.String)) from ServletContext class for this purpose. It will return Set with directory-style listing of resources for specified (web-application mapped) path.

If you want to read content of file specified by mapped path, you can use method [getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) from ServletContext returning InputStream for specified resource.

Answer (score -1):

```
java.io.File dir = new java.io.File("/fonts");
String[] files = dir.list();
```